# The variable storing the number of rows is not storing any number above 26

Tags: c, int, range

When I am running the following C program, the variable `r` is not taking value above the number `26`. Even when I entered the number of rows 40(say), the number of rows is 26. However, if the number of rows entered is less than 26, then the program is working perfectly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int r, i, j;
    printf("Enter the number of rows");
    scanf("%d", &r);

    for (i = r; i >= 1; i--) {
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can not reproduce.
`r` can store more than 26 numbers.

Comment: I am using Code::Blocks.In that IDE whenever I am running the program, the number of rows getting printed is only 26. It is not going above that.

Comment: Maybe you didn't compile properly. So, recompile and check again. The above code works perfectly on my machine.

Comment: I think that it is the number of lines displayed on the screen, not `r`.

Comment: Well maybe that is the case,but the display is showing only 26 rows. Why is the display not showing more than 26 rows?

Comment: If scrolling is not possible, the console buffer is small. For example,  you can insert code that stops every 10 lines of display.

Comment: change  buffer size of the terminal to sufficient no of lines. then you could scroll.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY can you elaborate your above comment?

Comment: E.g. `int line_count = 0; for(i=r;i>=1;i--){`...`printf("\n");
    if(++line_count % 10 == 0){
     char c[2];
     printf("Enter any letter:");fflush(stdout);
     scanf("%1s", c);
    }`

Comment: @Binary_10 how to do that?

Comment: Right-click on the CMD prompt's Title bar > Properties > Layout > Screen buffer size will let you increase the screen buffer size. (On Windows) . There's no bug in the above posted code